# Custom Cell not getting redrawn three20

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20, uitableview

i have an awkward problem where calling to `[self invalidateModel];` does not redraw my custom cells.

I have a TTTableViewController with an action sheet that allows to order the display of a table when pressed. The data gets redrawn correctly but the cells are not redrawn. Instead there are reused.

**To illustrate better :**
In my `- (void)layoutSubviews {` of my CustomTableItemCell class i have this :

```
if (bookmarked) {
        UIImage *bookmark = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bookmarked@2x.png"];
        TTImageView *bookmarkView = [[TTImageView alloc] init];
        bookmarkView.defaultImage = bookmark;
        bookmarkView.frame = CGRectMake(297, 0, 16, 27);
        [self.contentView addSubview:bookmarkView];
        TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(bookmarkView);
}
```

Basically if I get a bookmarked item, I want to display a ribbon on the right of my cell. This ribbon gets display correctly.
When I reorder my cell with the action sheet method and call invalidateModel, the first cell which didn't have any ribon gets putten at a place where was previously a ribbonned item but without redrawing the cell, thus giving a ribon to an item without ribbon.

**Code source :**
This is my createDatasource function of my TTTableViewController :

```
- (void)createModel {
    self.dataSource = [ServiceRequestDetailedDataSource viewDataSource:self.typeOfAction andOrderBy:orderBy];
    // If dataSource nil, show an empty Message
    if (self.dataSource == nil) {
        [self showEmpty:YES];
    }
}
```

This is my action sheet action of my TTTableViewController that change the orderBy and calls invalidate model :

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.orderBy = @"portfolio";
    [self invalidateModel];
}
```

**Any tips would be great, I am really stuck here :'(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just use reuseidentifier. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [self reload] would help you update cells view. Call it after model invalidation

Comment: allready tried it, same goes for needdisplay. Nothing worked so far :'( I'm thinking there is something to do with the reuseidentifier. But what ?